# Sorting values consisting of chars and numbers in an List<Tuple<>>() or asp:ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, sorting, listview

I have an Tuple List and I'm filling this list with all directorys of an folder and bind it to an asp:ListView with this code:

```
List<string> directoryContent = new List<string>(Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(dirPath);
List<Tuple<string, string>> directoryList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < directoryContent.Count; i++)
{
    FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(directoryContent[i]);
    if (attr.ToString().Equals("Directory"))
    {
        String str = directoryContent[i].Remove(0, dirPath.Length);
        string count = Directory.GetFiles(directoryContent[i], "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length.ToString();
        directoryList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(str, count));
    }
}

directoryListView.DataSource = directoryList;
directoryListView.DataBind();
```

For example the found directories are

- 12
- 566
- 10001
- 10
- templates
- files

What would be the best way to sort the List or the ListView in this way? Thank you in advance.
I need to sort the directory that they are sorted in this order:

- files
- templates
- 10
- 12
- 566
- 1001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq for that.

```
//test data
List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
    "12",
    "566",
    "10001",
    "10",
    "templates",
    "files"
};

int tempInt;

//filter the numbers from the list and sort
var listNumbers = list.Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out tempInt)).Select(y => Convert.ToInt32(y)).OrderBy(z => z);

//filter the strings from the list and sort
var listStrings = list.Where(x => !int.TryParse(x, out tempInt)).OrderBy(y => y);

//join the two lists again
var orderedList = listStrings.Concat(listNumbers.Select(y => y.ToString())).ToList();
```

Update for Tuple List

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
{
    new Tuple<string, string>("12", "NA"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("566", "NA"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("10001", "NA"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("10", "NA"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("templates", "NA"),
    new Tuple<string, string>("files", "NA")
};

int tempInt;

//filter the numbers from the list and sort
var listNumbers = list.Where(x => int.TryParse(x.Item1, out tempInt)).Select(y => new Tuple<int, string>(Convert.ToInt32(y.Item1), y.Item2)).OrderBy(z => z.Item1);

//filter the strings from the list and sort
var listStrings = list.Where(x => !int.TryParse(x.Item1, out tempInt)).OrderBy(z => z.Item1);

//join the two lists again
var orderedList = listStrings.Concat(listNumbers.Select(y => new Tuple<string, string>(y.Item1.ToString(), y.Item2))).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fantastic with List<> but I do have a Tuple List. Sorry that I did not write it more specific in my example. Do you know an similar solution working with tuples, too?

Comment: Updated my answer